# Hover on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

This menu [in the middle of this page](http://www.luxeroad-services.fr) is working well, but on a Mac tablet (IOS system) it is giving this [bug hover menu on Mac IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/354hf.jpg). I suspect the problem to come from the "hover" function. Here is the html code :

```css
.accueil2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
}

.hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 60vmin;
  height: 60vmin;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -10vmin;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.2) translatez(0px);
  transform: scale(0.2) translatez(0px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
}

.a1,
.a2,
.a3,
.a4,
.a5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 47.5%;
  height: 47.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5) translateZ(0px);
  transform: scale(.5) translateZ(0px);
  background: #585247;
}

a .div1,
a .div2,
a .div3,
a .div4 {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
  /*lien haut gauche*/
  border-radius: 40vmin 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 110% 110%;
  transform-origin: 110% 110%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s .15s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .4s .15s;
  transition: transform .4s .15s;
  transition: transform .4s .15s, -webkit-transform .4s .15s;
}

a:nth-child(1) div {
  /*haut gauche*/
  background: #E3DFD2;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  /*lien haut droite*/
  border-radius: 0 40vmin 0 0;
  left: 52.5%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: -10% 110%;
  transform-origin: -10% 110%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .4s .2s;
  transition: transform .4s .2s;
  transition: transform .4s .2s, -webkit-transform .4s .2s;
}

a:nth-child(2) div {
  background: #E3DFD2;
}

a:nth-child(3) {
  /*lien en bas à gauche*/
  border-radius: 0 0 0 40vmin;
  top: 52.5%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 110% -10%;
  transform-origin: 110% -10%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s .25s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .4s .25s;
  transition: transform .4s .25s;
  transition: transform .4s .25s, -webkit-transform .4s .25s;
}

a:nth-child(3) div {
  background: #E3DFD2;
}

a:nth-child(4) {
  /*lien en bas à droite*/
  border-radius: 0 0 40vmin 0;
  top: 52.5%;
  left: 52.5%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: -10% -10%;
  transform-origin: -10% -10%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s .3s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .4s .3s;
  transition: transform .4s .3s;
  transition: transform .4s .3s, -webkit-transform .4s .3s;
}

a:nth-child(4) div {
  background: #E3DFD2;
}

.a5 {
  /*lien centre*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
  left: 22.5%;
  top: 22.5%;
  border-radius: 50vmin;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5vmin #E3DFD2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#faceA {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
  left: 22.5%;
  top: 22.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

#faceB {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
  left: 22.5%;
  top: 22.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.a5.flipMe {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.spanout {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 25vmin;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #585247;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
  transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.spanin {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ACA696;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.spanin:after,
.spanin:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}

.spanin:after {
  top: 1.5vmin;
}

.spanout:hover+.wrap,
.wrap:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.8) translateZ(0px);
  transform: scale(.8) translateZ(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.spanout:hover+.wrap a,
.wrap:hover a {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translatez(0px);
  transform: scale(1) translatez(0px);
}

a:hover div {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0px);
  transform: translatez(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="accueil2">
  <span class="spanout">
         <span class="spanin">
         </span>
  </span>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" class="a1">
      <div class="div1"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="a2">
      <div class="div2"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="a3">
      <div class="div3"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="a4">
      <div class="div4"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="a5">
      <div id="faceA">A</div>
      <div id="faceB">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've retagged this as Safari since that's the browser used on iOS. The `iOS` tag is mostly for programming native applications.

Comment: @tadman actually you are looking for `mobile-safari`

Comment: @DerekBrown Even better! Thanks.

Comment: What problem is it giving you exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is giving the problem shown in the picture I attached. On hover the .a5 positions itself underneath the .a1 .a2 .a3 .a4 when it should be on top. I don't have access to an IOS tablet so the picture has been transmitted to me by my client. He says the navigator he uses is Firefox, on a Mac tablet. I don't have that problem with Windows or Android.